# Push is not coming In Distribution mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification

Hello All I have problem of push is not coming in distribution mode but it is coming in development mode.Some times it comes on distribution mode but this time it is not coming.

Can you suggest me what is going wrong with me

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another Push Certificate (the Distribution Push Certificate ;) for the Distribution mode and you need to sign your application with this certificate

Comment: I have distribution certificate but it is not coming.Some days ago it was fine I think there is another issue I also have provisioning associated with distribution along with this i also make 2 more provisioning and ck.pem but result was same

Comment: You Need to send the Push over the Distribution cert, use the Distribution Push Server from Apple and Spur application Needs to ne signed Wirth the Distribution cert

Comment: Thanks but the problem has been solved There was error from web development side he got the error and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are created `.pem` file with `Distribution certificate` and check that `SSL Server` is pointed to `gateway.push.apple.com`

Comment: Yeah I have checked it some days ago it was fine i think there is some problem with it